ROCm not working on Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop
I was following steps from this official website to install ROCm and at the intall rocm step I faced following issue
https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/ubuntu.html
pserver@pserver-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ sudo apt install rocm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hipsolver : Depends: libcholmod3 but it is not installable
             Depends: libsuitesparseconfig5 but it is not installable
 rocm-gdb : Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not installable
            Depends: libncurses5 but it is not installable
            Depends: libpython3.10 but it is not installable or
                     libpython3.8 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Running this command fixed the problem.
sudo add-apt-repository -y -s deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe

AMD's rocm drivers are still being built for 22.04, so we need to add the jammy repo's for the missing dependencies.
You can find more info at the links below:
https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/3rd-party/pytorch-install.html
https://github.com/nktice/AMD-AI#-for-ubuntu-2304-2310-and-2404--
